# Understanding this unix script

Tags: bash, unix

This script was written by my tutor but I don't understand it.
Can someone please explain it to me.

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -size +${2}c -size -${3}c
```

This script suppose to accept three command line arguments: directory name, minimum file size in bytes and maximum file size in bytes. So when running it, it will be like this:

```
./script.sh /home/Desktop/file 5000 10000
```

And then the files size between 5000 and 10000 will be echoed to the screen.

Dose anyone know another way of doing the same?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -size +${2}c -size -${3}c
    |___|     |_____|       |_____|
      |          |             |
This is the    This is      This is the
first argument the second   third argument
passed while    argument
 running the
  script
```

`find` utility syntax is to search `specified path` for files which can be identified depending on the `options` chosen.

```
-size n[ckMGTP]
 True if the file's size, rounded up, in 512-byte blocks is n.  
 If n is followed by a c, then the primary is true if the 
 file's size is n bytes (characters).
```

Using `+` in front of `second argument` means we are looking for files `greater` then the number specified. Similarly `-` means the files to be displayed should be less than the size specified.

By passing three arguments to your script, means we are giving `$1` as the path to be searched which in your case is `/home/Desktop/file`. The second argument defines the condition that files should be greater than the specified argument which is `5000`. The final argument is for specifying that the files should be less than the specified size which is `10000`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This script runs as your teacher says.

Error `"find: Invalid argument +c to -size.` is becausse you don't inform about second argument to script. Then ${2} has no value and script tries to execute:

```
find your_path -size +$c -size -$c
```

You can modify your script in order to [check for number or arguments](http://www.linuxweblog.com/bash-argument-numbers-check):

```
#!/bin/bash
EXPECTED_ARGS=3
E_BADARGS=65
HLP_ARG="path min_size max_size"
if [ $# -ne $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` $HLP_ARG"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi    

find $1 -size +${2}c -size -${3}c
```

Comment: Why `E_BADARGS=65` and not `E_USAGE=64`?

Comment: You are free to select your own [exit status](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bourne-shell-exit-status-examples/) code.

Comment: Rather than requiring 3 arguments, it is often better to simply set reasonable defaults: find $1 ${2+-size +${2}c} ${3+-size -${3}c}

Comment: @WilliamPursell, nice appointment. But just to catch answer requeriments: "This script suppose to accept three command line arguments"